# Why are my VS2008 watches showing incorrect values?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, watch

I have a string variable and a string constant. Both should be the same value (I'm testing for equality in a conditional). The 'correct' values of both should be "scl". While debugging, if I put a watch on each, look at them in the 'locals' windows, or hover over them, the value displayed is "sd", which is the value of a different constant in the class (there are many other constants and variables in the class that are displaying values correctly). If I insert a Debug.WriteLine for the variable/constant value in question, (in the same scope as the watch) the output window prints the correct value of each. For the life of me, I can't figure out why this is happening, or how to correct it.

Comment: You may have already tried it, but my first thought is, have you tried restarting VS?

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to clean and rebuild your project. Some of the debug info sounds off.

Comment: Already did both. But thanks for suggesting.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimization (/Ox)?  If you do this, the values of variables are not always up to date in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have fixed it by changing the value of the constant, running a debugging session, then changing the value back to what it should be. Perhaps this cleared out some kind of debugging cache.

Thanks for the help all!

Comment: I think I know what happened. The semantics of a constant are supposed to be that the value is *constant* for *all eternity*. The compiler assumes that a constant *never* changes, even between versions of an assembly. Therefore, when assembly B references a constant C from assembly A, the compiler *embeds* the value of C in B. If you then change the constant in A, B still has the original value, and will until you recompile B. If you want the value to be something that is picked up at runtime, use a property or readonly field instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a lazy loaded property?  I've had issues like this in the past where I've done something like this (horribly contrived example, but it will do)

```
public ClassWithMoo
{
   private string moo;

   public string Moo
   {
      get
      { 
         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.moo)) this.moo = "Baa";
         return this.moo; 
      }
      set
      {
         this.moo = value;
      }
   }
}

public ClassThatUsesMoo
{
    ClassWithMoo cow = new ClassWithMoo();

    // breakpoint here would show cow.Moo = "Baa" 
    // This is because the debugger/watch window will instantiate the property!

    someCodeHere();

    cow.Moo = "Moo"; 
    debug.WriteLine(cow.Moo); // outputs 'Moo' now that it has been set properly
}
```

Comment: That would make sense. However, nothing like that is being done. Besides, one of the erroneous values is of a constant, so reassigning the constant to the proper value could not be done.